# Does this property of sets and functions hold for a general topos?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

In the category of sets and set-theoretic functions, every arrow can be obtained by only using the universal property of the small coproducts of $1=\{ 0 \}$ applied to the coprojections that exhibit them as a coproducts. In the following sense.

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a map between sets. Then $X$ is the coproduct of a $X$-indexed family of $1$'s, that is, $X=\sum_{x \in X}1$, and the same holds for $Y=\sum_{y \in Y}1$. Let $\{\iota_x\colon 1 \to X\}_{x \in X}$ and $\{\eta_y\colon 1\to Y \}_{y \in Y}$ be the coprojections that exhibit $X$ and $Y$ as those coproducts (respectively). Since $\{\eta_{f(x)} \}_{x \in X}$ is a cocone of the family $\{1_x=1 \}_{x \in X}$, we get unique a map $g \colon X \to Y$ such that $g \circ \iota_x =\eta_{f(x)}$, for every $x \in X$. The point is that, clearly, this map $g$ happens to be $f$. Hence, we see that every arrow $X \to Y$ can be obtained by invoking the universal property of the coproduct $X=\sum_{x\in X}1$ on an $X$-indexed subfamily of $\{\eta_y\colon 1\to Y \}_{y \in Y}$ (noticing that it is as cocone of $\{1_x=1 \}_{x \in X}$).

I was wondering if this also holds for an arbitrary topos $\mathcal{E}$. In detail, if $X$ and $Y$ are sets and $1$ is the terminal object of $\mathcal{E}$, is it the case that every arrow $\sum_{x \in X}1\to\sum_{y \in Y}1$ [assuming that these coproducts exist or that, for instance, $\mathcal{E}$ is cocomplete] can be obtained by invoking the universal property of the coproduct $\sum_{x \in X}1$ on an $X$-indexed subfamily of the family of coprojections that exhibit $\sum_{y\in Y}1$ as a coproduct (suppose that we fixed such a family before for both $\sum_{x \in X}1$ and $\sum_{y \in Y}1$)?

If $\phi$ is an arrow $\sum_{x \in X}1\to\sum_{y \in Y}1$ and $\{\iota_x\colon 1 \to \sum_{x \in X}\}_{x \in X}$ and $\{\eta_y\colon 1\to \sum_{y \in Y}1 \}_{y \in Y}$ are our fixed families of coprojections, we can consider the arrows $\phi \circ \iota_x \colon 1 \to \sum_{1 \in Y}1$, for $x \in X$. Clearly, the answer would be yes if we proved that, for every $x\in X$, there is $y \in Y$ such that $\phi \circ \iota_x=\eta_y$. Is this the case?

Comment: If I can propose a condensation of your question, it seems that you're asking: Is it true in every topos $\mathcal E$ that for every set $Y$, the natural map 
$\sum_Y \mathcal E(1,1)\to \mathcal E(1,\sum_Y 1)$ is an isomorphism? Now, there's an issue that coproducts indexed by $Y$ may not exist in every topos, so we should also assume $Y$ is finite or that $\mathcal E$ has all small coproducts.

Comment: How do you define $\displaystyle\sum_{x\in X} 1$ in an arbitrary topos ?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, you're right. So my question becomes: whenever these two coproducts exist, is it the case that ... ?

Comment: Ah! Actually my question arises from a situation in which I was assuming that $\mathcal{E}$ is cocomplete. Then if you want we can also assume this from the beginning.

Comment: But you can't take a coproduct over something that isn't a set. I mean, sometimes you can, but it would be good if here you precised what you mean

Comment: In fact I am only considering small coproducts here. Then, if $\mathcal{E}$ has small colimits, all should be fine, right?

Comment: In a topos, a morphism $1\to1+1$ need not be of the form you propose. That form would make it one of the two coprojections (also called injections). Consider, for example, the topos of pairs of sets (and pairs of functions). Its terminal object has two complementary subobjects given by the pairs of sets $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.  There's a unique morphism sending the first of these to the first summand in $1+1$ and sending the second subobjects to the second summand.

Comment: Thank you, Andreas!